# Convergence problem

Tags: probability, mean, convergence

I practiced some problem (not homework) as below.

Suppose that $X_1,X_2,\cdots$ are independent and identically distributed real-valued random variables with $E|X_1|=\infty$. Show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P({|X_n| \geq a\cdot n})=\infty$ for each $a >0$.

I obtained that $\infty = E(|X_n|) = \int_{0}^\infty P(|X_n| >x)dx \leq \sum_{n=0}^\infty P(|X_n|>n)$, but I couldn't get the final step $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P({|X_n| \geq an})=\infty$ for each $a >0$ ( or can I use the statment to imply the result?) Please provide some hints, thanks!

Comment: Consider $Y_n = X_n/a$.

Comment: Looks like homework.  Add the homework tag.

Comment: $a$ or $a_n$ ?.. If this is $a$ there is nothing to do since $P(|X_n| \geq a)$ does not depend on $n$. Hence this is surely $(a_n)$ but what are the hypotheses about the sequence $(a_n)$ ?

Comment: Hi, @StéphaneLaurent. Perhaps you misread the problem? :)

Comment: @cardinal, Possible because the LaTeX does not appear as compiled in my navigator... But ok, now I see: this is $a \times n$

Comment: @MichaelChernick It's a question from Probability and measure by Billingsley, and this is not homework (I'm preparing for my qualification exam.)

Comment: @DouglasZare, thanks, I got the points: $ E(|Yn|) = E\left(\left|\frac{X_n} {a}\right|\right) = \infty$.

Comment: @Stéphane: Yes, without LaTeX rendering, it would be difficult to parse! Your boss should really update your computer's browser capabilities so that you can waste time more efficiently. ;-)

Comment: @cardinal This is Firefox portable. Sometimes the LaTeX rendering works well, sometimes it does not work, I don't know why.

Comment: Same behavior here, Stéphane.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that $E[Y]=\int_0^\infty P\{Y\geq t\}\,dt$, for nonnegative $Y$.

[image]

We see that the $X_i$'s don't need to be independent. Identically distributed is enough.

P.S. Of course, $p_0=1$.

Comment: (+1) For most readers, the very first line under your graph should be more than enough. I was just about to mention the oddity of the iid assumption in the question statement; I'm glad to see you made an edit to point this out! :-)

Comment: Sharp as usual, Mr. cardinal.

Comment: @Zen, could you please have a look at my problem? https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/70095/a-new-convergence-problem-for-the-conditional-expectation?noredirect=1#comment102182_70095